# Multiple "where" -s from one table into one view

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "users" with 4 fields: ID, UNAME, NAME, SHOW_NAME.

I wish to put this data into one view so that if SHOW_NAME is not set, "UNAME" should be selected as "NAME", otherwise "NAME".

My current query:

```
SELECT id AS id, uname AS name 
FROM users 
WHERE show_name != 1 
 UNION 
SELECT id AS id, name AS name 
FROM users 
WHERE show_name = 1
```

This generally works, but it does seem to lose the primary key (NaviCat telling me "users_view does not have a primary key...") - which I think is bad.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine. I'm not sure why it's complaining about the loss of a primary key.

I will offer one piece of advice. When you *know* that there can be no duplicates in your union (such as the two parts being `when x = 1` and `when x != 1`), you should use `union all`.

The `union` clause will attempt to remove duplicates which, in this case, is a waste of time.

If you want more targeted assistance, it's probably best if you post the details of the view and the underlying table. Views themselves don't tend to have primary keys or indexes, relying instead on the underlying tables.

So this may well be a problem with your "NaviCat" product (whatever that *is*) expecting to see a primary key (in other words, it's not built very well for views).

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding your question correctly, you should be able to just use a CASE statement like below for your logic

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SHOW_NAME ==1 THEN NAME ELSE UNAME END
FROM users
```

Comment: that seems to be needlessly complicated given the nature of the query.

Comment: This actually works well (I think) and I don't get the "no primary key" message with it (have to use just one = though). [ select id as id, (case when show_name = 1 then name else uname end) as name from users ]

Answer (score 1):

This can likely be better written as the following:

SELECT id AS id, IF(show_name == 1, name, uname) AS name 
FROM users

Comment: Just be aware that solutions involving per-row functions will not usually scale well. The best solution is actually the one posted by the OP since a DBMS can run both queries in parallel using the indexes at full speed, then just combine them. The per-row function solutions are fine if your tables stay relatively small (which may well be the case here).

Comment: If nothing else, the OP can benchmark both solutions and see which works for him.  We had a similar union in a production environment and switched to the conditional column and found a noticeable difference.